# Static site generator with dynamic pages

Tags: static-site-generator

I am looking for a static site generator that has dynamic pages support, like [Middleman](https://middlemanapp.com/) has. (I am having trouble with Middleman not reading data files in configuration.)

I want a page, from a template, to be generated for each item in an array, with the corresponding array item passed to the template.

Preferably this is in Node.js, but other languages are OK, too.

Comment: "I am having trouble with Middleman not reading data files in configuration" - sounds like a question for the Middleman forum, or one of our sister sites

Comment: Caleb, did you ever find a solution? If so, please post it here as an answer, and accept it, in order to help others in future

Comment: I did not find an answer

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Perhaps you could comment those below as to why they are not a good match? That might help others who are looking for something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`HUGO`](https://gohugo.io/).
It is written in GO and it has a nice list of [templates](https://themes.gohugo.io/) which look really amazing.

Some websites using it:

- https://letsencrypt.org/
- https://www.hartwell-insurance.com/
- https://promotive.es/
- https://support.1password.com/

Comment: Can you give a **specific example** of how you are able to generate a page per each item in an array?

Answer (score 0):

Wyam is quite powerful and extensible: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExploringWyamANETStaticSiteContentGenerator.aspx

Comment: Can you give a **specific example** of how you are able to generate a page per each item in an array?

Comment: Unfortunately I still haven't got around to playing with Wyam as much as I wanted, so I can't help you at this time. I suggest you take a look at the project site (Wyam.io) and maybe get in touch with the contributors: https://github.com/Wyamio/Wyam/graphs/contributors

Answer (score -1):

Jekyll lets you use Liquid markup which could iterate over a loop and generate the pages you need. There are also plugins which might help, links below:

https://jekyllrb.com/

https://github.com/avillafiorita/jekyll-datapage_gen

Comment: Are you sure Jekyll can generate multiple pages in a loop? What you linked to seems more like it can loop over something and create many entries on one page. That's also what I've done with Jekyll so far.